# How to add full height for a element inside an element in CSS or Angularjs Dinamically

Tags: css, angular

Idea is do not use vertical or horizontal scroll bar in body section. I have a div which is having css like this:

```
display: flex;
height: 100%;
```

I want inside div height to be fully responsive. The height should be auto adjusted based on the height of the device. for inside div we can have scroll bar no problem based on the data.

Hope you guys understood my question, please help.

Comment: Just simplly use position relative height and width should be 100% whats the problem in this ?

Comment: Inside element is table, I given those css but not coming as required

Answer (score 0):

as you don't want scroll on the body but inside your main div.you can achieve using following css and html.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    // you content goes here...
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css for `.main` class and for `.content` class are as follows.

```
.main{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

here is the demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpLZqd

i hope this will help.